# How to get the value of a measurement transmitted by a BLE device?

Tags: esp8266, esp32, mqtt, ble

I would like to use a BLE temperature sensor (such as the Inkbird IBS-TH1 Mini BLE Sensor), however, I want to be able to display the temperature measurements in my own website. To do this I am planning to have an ESP32, which would intercept the temperatures sensor's BLE messages (and then send them to Firebase Realtime Database via WiFi). I know how to use the ESP32 to find advertising devices, however, I am not sure how to receive the measurements the sensor is transmitting. I have seen libraries such as the ESPHome or ESP32-mqtt-room, but I was wondering whether there is a way to bypass them? Is it neccesary to use mqtt or mosquito? Or is it possible to achieve this using solely the Arduino BLE library?

Any help would be appreciated!